# Calculate distance between columns of two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, distance

I have two data frames that contain values for different people in each column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Anna":[1.5,-2,2.5],
    "Bob":[2.5,-3,3.5],
    "Cam":[3.5,-4,4.5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Dave":[1,-2.5,2],
    "Emma":[2,-3.5,3],
    "Fred":[3,-4.5,4]})

print(df1)

   Anna  Bob  Cam
0   1.5  2.5  3.5
1  -2.0 -3.0 -4.0
2   2.5  3.5  4.5

print(df2)

   Dave  Emma  Fred
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1  -2.5  -3.5  -4.5
2   2.0   3.0   4.0
```

Is there a faster way of getting a distance matrix from each person in df1 to each person in df2 than this double loop?

```
results = []

for n1 in df1.columns:
    results.append([])
    for n2 in df2.columns:
        results[-1].append(math.dist(df1[n1], df2[n2]))


res_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
res_df.columns = df1.columns
res_df.index = df2.columns

print(res_df)


        Anna        Bob         Cam
Dave    0.866025    1.658312    3.278719
Emma    2.179449    0.866025    1.658312
Fred    3.840573    2.179449    0.866025
```

Comment: the code looks efficient.  Have you used timeit to measure performance

Comment: @GoldenLion I have not, as I'm not very familiar with the library. I think I'll wait a bit to see what other answers people suggest, then time each proposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) from [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) and make a new [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) :

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

res_df = pd.DataFrame(cdist(df1.T, df2.T), columns=df1.columns, index=df2.columns)
```

​
Output :

```
print(res_df)
​
          Anna       Bob       Cam
Dave  0.866025  1.658312  3.278719
Emma  2.179449  0.866025  1.658312
Fred  3.840573  2.179449  0.866025
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Anna": [1.5, -2, 2.5],
    "Bob": [2.5, -3, 3.5],
    "Cam": [3.5, -4, 4.5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Dave": [1, -2.5, 2],
    "Emma": [2, -3.5, 3],
    "Fred": [3, -4.5, 4]})

# Convert data frames to NumPy arrays
arr1 = df1.to_numpy()
arr2 = df2.to_numpy()

# Calculate the Euclidean distance using broadcasting
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((arr1[:, :, None] - arr2[:, None, :]) ** 2, axis=0))

# Create the result data frame
res_df = pd.DataFrame(dist, index=df2.columns, columns=df1.columns)

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(res_df)
```

Output:

```
   Anna  Bob  Cam
0   1.5  2.5  3.5
1  -2.0 -3.0 -4.0
2   2.5  3.5  4.5

   Dave  Emma  Fred
0   1.0   2.0   3.0
1  -2.5  -3.5  -4.5
2   2.0   3.0   4.0

          Anna       Bob       Cam
Dave  0.866025  1.658312  3.278719
Emma  2.179449  0.866025  1.658312
Fred  3.840573  2.179449  0.866025
```